# How to add a comments to jira issue using rest api

Tags: jira-rest-api

Refered AnotherJiraClient code found in nuget package

Refered this
https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Add+Comment
to add a comment.

```
    var request = new RestRequest()
    {
        Resource = ResourceUrls.Comment(),
        RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,
        Method = Method.POST
    };
    request.AddBody(addComment);//{"body":"Something"}

    return Execute<BasicIssue>(request, HttpStatusCode.Created);
```

But always returned with status not found?
How to add comments using Jira REST API?

Comment: Auth related problem? https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+APIs#JIRARESTAPIs-Authentication

Comment: but i can fetch the comments i can do all operations using GET.but when i need to post it says status not found.

Comment: Same here, user has rights to access and comment on the issue. The same happens when using the JIRA Java Client API from https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JRJC/Home

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was I mssing in the code. I need to provide the comment as an json object.

```
library(httr)
library(RJSONIO)

x <- toJSON(list(body = "Adding a new Comment"))

POST("https://xxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/comment",body = x, authenticate(userid,password, "basic"), add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json"), verbose())
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Jira's REST API to append a comment . See this link https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/How-to-add-comments-using-rest-api/qaq-p/571351