# Adding comment to a JIRA issue ticket using REST API in R

Tags: r

I would like to add more comments to an existing JIRA ticket using REST API pro grammatically from R

I tried the following  based on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566363/how-to-add-a-comments-to-jira-issue-using-rest-api) in this forum but did not work:

```
library(httr)

POST("https://xxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/issueId/comment",body = "New Comment", authenticate(userid,password, "basic"))
```

Comment: Is there any error feedback?  This is the first thing to check.

Comment: I get HTTP/1.1 400  error

Comment: Are you certain that your credentials are correct?  As a test, can you try calling `GET()` on a get endpoint using the `httr` library?

Comment: I did. I am able to create a JIRA ticket with values for custom fields and default fields from R. But having problem updating an existing ticket from R.

Comment: I just figured out what I missed in my code. Apparently I have to pass the comment as a json object as I do for creating a new JIRA issue ticket.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the accepted answer in your [forum link](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/How-to-add-comments-using-rest-api/qaq-p/571351), which suggests the following POST using `curl`:

> curl -u admin:admin -X POST --data '{"body": "comment."}' -H "Content-type: application/json" http://localhost:2990/jira/rest/api/2/issue/TEST-1/comment

Note carefully that the body is JSON content, with the content type also being set as JSON.  You may try doing the same in your call to the `POST()` function from `httr`:

```
POST("https://xxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/issueId/comment",
    body = '{"body": "comment."}', authenticate(userid, password, "basic"),
    encode="raw")
```